# Scheduled Task returning 0x080070532

Tags: windows-server-2008, scheduled-tasks

I have a scheduled task running on a Windows Server 2008 R2 that is now suddenly returning a "Last Run Result" of `0x080070532`.
Searching for this gets me no hits at all, and the eventlog on the server does not contain any information around this error.
I can tell you that the task did not run successfully at the specified time.

Has anyone seen this error code before ?

Comment: The result you got was probably 0x80070532 (8 digits hexadecimal), which is usual for error codes, so it may well be that you added a leading zero by accident.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe 0x80070532 is ERROR_PASSWORD_EXPIRED.